# countinue the timer even after transfer to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

- i have an asp page in which i write C# code for taking data from one
  table and update the another table.
- now i want to countinously check one level in first level if reaches
  to throuseld than i want to update another table

**so i use ajax timer control**

the code is given

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="10000" > 
  <!--we have to put 24*60*60*1000=86400000 milli-seconds for one day-->
</asp:Timer>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

</asp:ScriptManager></pre>
```

- i have write c# code for updating database in timer tick event i is
  working okk
- now if a user transfer from this page to another page than the timer 
  will not work and database will not update

what to do?

Comment: why for god's sake are you wanting to do this with asp.net? wouldn't eg a console with utilization of quartz.net be a far more better option?!

Comment: i make web site in which i countinous display how much amount of waste is collected in dustbin...i put sensor on dustbin .so i want to update my database reguraly

Comment: for this job you can eg query the service, which provides the information over a wcf-interface ... this interface may be queried with ajax ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to execute code on the server without involving the client, you shouldn't use ajax or any other client triggered approach.

Start a server side timer or background thread in global.asax to do your work.

Comment: i wouldn't dare to use asp.net for this: what if app recycles, ... rather go for a console/service/ ...

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, thats right, but often you have no rights to execute separate services on a server or you want to have a single deployment. So i think its a valid option to start background tasks inside an ASP.NET app. But sure, you have to worry about AppPool recycling. But thats no problem with App_Start or some similar mechanism.

Comment: When you create an asp.net project there should be two files included:  global.asax and global.asax.cs. There you can write code that hooks on events like Application_Start or BeginRequest. See this article for an intro: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=126